# Prove by induction the formula for the sum up to $n$ terms of a geometric sequence

Tags: proof-verification, induction

This question is a little unorthodox, but here is the context

I was sitting a past exam paper in preparation for an upcoming mock examination and one question, worth $4$ marks, asked to

> Prove that the sum of the first $n$ terms of a geometric sequence is given by
>
> $$S_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$
>   where $n\geq 1$

The actual method the mark scheme brings to light is the following

$$S_n=a+ar+ar^2+\ldots+ar^{n-1}$$
$$rS_n=ar+ar^2+ar^3+\ldots+ar^n$$
$$S_n-rS_n=a-ar^n$$
$$S_n(1-r)=a(1-r^n)$$
$$S_n=\frac{a(1-r^n)}{1-r}$$

Although to me the question was yelling out induction, so this was my approach:

**Base step:**

Let $n=1$
$$S_n=\frac{a(1-r)}{1-r}=a$$
$\implies$ The given equation holds for $n=1$, hence we assume it holds for $n=k$, and proceed to test it for $n=k+1$,

**Inductive step:**

$$S_{k+1}=\frac{a(1-r^{k})}{1-r} + ar^k$$
$$S_{k+1}=\frac{a-ar^{k}+ar^k-ar^{k+1}}{1-r}$$ $$S_{k+1}=\frac{a-ar^{k+1}}{1-r}$$
$$S_{k+1}=\frac{a(1-r^{k+1})}{1-r}$$
$\implies$ The given equation holds $\forall n\in\mathbb N$

The question in short is: do you reckon my approach is still worth the $4$ marks? I’m asking because I’m assuming the collective knowledge of this website on proof by induction is far beyond my own knowledge of induction.

Any responses and amendments are appreciated.

Comment: Of course it's still worth the full points. Induction is just as valid as any other method, though perhaps less enlightening at times. The concept hardly changes between more 'advanced' problems either (besides maybe some tweaking for finite induction), which is what makes it such a reliable tool in an enumerated proof.

Comment: Induction is of course worth the full points. In the original proof, induction is only hidden in the $\cdots$. One must realize that $S_n$ is defined by induction, as is every sum from $1$ to $n$. The correct way to prove that $r \sum a r^k = \sum a r^{k+1}$ is induction.